How do I count unique but ignore one set word
Can any one tell me how to use countunique and ignore one word in a list.
=COUNTUNIQUE(C53:C72).
I wish to ignore the word "blank" in a column.
I'm unsure how to convert the countunique to exclude 1 or then 2  certain critera.

Excel does not have COUNTUNIQUE, please read the tags, The google-sheets tag specifically says not to use it with the excel tag.

What do you mean by ... to exclude 1 or then 2 certain critera? Are you expecting to ignore multiple words other than blank? Or you just want to ignore the word blank only?

I want to ignore the word "blank" not a blank space, also would like to understand how to then if possible ignore more than one word so I can change the formula as needed thanks

Combine COUNTUNIQUE with COUNTIF and MIN. Something like:
=COUNTUNIQUE(C53:C72) - MIN(COUNTIF(C53:C72, "blank"), 1)

Don't have access to Google Sheets now to test it.
